# Verifying $\mu(E)=\nu(E)+\sup\{ \mu(W)- \nu(W): W \subseteq E$ with $\nu(W)< \infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,B)$ be a measure space and let $\mu, \nu$ be measures such that $\mu \geq \nu$. Define the set function $\lambda: B \to [0, \infty]$ by $\lambda(E)= \sup\{ \mu(W)- \nu(W): W \subseteq E$ with $\nu(W)< \infty\}$ if $E$ is nonempty and $\lambda( \emptyset)=0$ as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693415/finding-an-example-where-a-measure-is-not-unique?rq=1).

Forget the question of whether or not $\lambda$ is a measure. I first want to know that, as a set function, we indeed have $\mu(E)=\nu(E)+\lambda(E)$ for any $E \in B$.

The equation is obvious if $\nu(E)= \infty$. But if $\nu(E)< \infty$, it is not clear to me how to proceed. I see that we will have $\lambda(E) \geq \mu(E)- \nu(E)$ but I don't know why the reverse inequality needs to hold.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu(W)=\infty$ for some $W\subseteq E$, the result is true.

Otherwise, for each integer $n$ there is a measurable set $W_n\subseteq E$ such that

$ (\mu- \nu)(W_n)>\lambda (E)-1/n.$ Without loss of generality, $W_n\subseteq W_{n+1}\subseteq \cdots\subseteq E$.

Then, $(\mu-\nu)(E)\ge (\mu-\nu)(\bigcup W_n)=\lim (\mu-\nu)(W_n)\ge \lambda(E).$

Comment: Hi, How would you consider the case where $\nu(E)= \infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [@Matematleta](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3561678/950650) suggested, for the case where $\mu(E) = \infty$ and $\nu(E) < \infty$ the result holds. So it suffices to consider the case $\nu(E) \leq \mu(E) < \infty$.

Let $W \subset E$. As $\nu(E) \leq \mu(E) < \infty$, $E - W \in B$. Further, by the incision property and the fact that $\mu \geq \nu$,

$$
  \mu (E - W) \geq \nu (E - W) \implies \mu (E) - \nu (E) \geq \mu (W) - \nu (W) \, .
$$

Because the above holds for all $W \subset E$ with $\nu (W) < \infty$, we can take supremum over $W$ to get

$$
  \mu (E) - \nu (E) \geq \sup _{W} \, [\mu (W) - \nu (W)] = \lambda (E) \\
  \implies \mu (E) \geq \nu (E) + \lambda (E)
$$